# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, mern

I am working on the MERN stack project. here I have one **endPoint** for users, user can update their details

```js
router.put('/updateuser/:id',fetchuser, async (req, res) => {
const {name, email, role, password} = req.body;
//create new user object
const newUser = {};
if(name){newUser.name = name};
if(email){newUser.email = email};
if(password){newUser.password = password};
if(role){newUser.role = role};role

     //Find the user will be updated and update it
    let user = await User.findById(req.params.id);
    if(!user){return res.status(404).send("note found")}

    if(user.user.toString() !== req.user.id){
      return res.status(401).send("Not Allowed");
       
    }

    user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: newUser},{ new:true})
    res.json({user});
})
```

endpoint not working showing error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')`
you can see the below image
[image: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString']

if anyone knows how to fix this Typos error please let me know

**Update:**
see the image to better understand
[image]

I think errors occur because I am using the Same name for user declare and My user model. but after changing  name error not resolved

Comment: clearly `user.user` is undefined. What have you looked at to try to debug this? It's hard to help without knowing a bunch more about your code, in particular what `User.findById` does.

Comment: Is it meant to say `user.id.toString() !== req.user.id`? Seems like you wanted to compare the user IDs but you did `user.user` instead of `user.id`

Answer (score -1):

The error here is trying to say that it cannot read the property 'toString' from the 'user' property, as the 'user' property is not defined or does not exists.

In your case it means that `user.user` is `undefined`, hence the compiler is not able to read 'toString' property. Maybe you meant to try something like:

```
if(user.toString() !== req.user.id)
```

Although I think you should first debug and check the value of 'user' returned by `User.findById` before checking for the condition and seeing what exactly is returned

Comment: hey  all thanks for the debug I solve My error I Just remove this line `if(user.user.toString() !== req.user.id){
      return res.status(401).send("Not Allowed");  }` and it works fine